# Cannot find view in node/express

Tags: node.js, express

As my username implies, I'm new to node.js. I'm trying to learn it. As part of this process, I'm working to setup a basic web site. This web site will show a couple of basic web pages and expose a single REST endpoint. The structure of my project is:

```
config.js
home.html
start.js
routes.js
server.js
resources
  css
    style.css
  images
    up.png
    down.png
  javascript
    home.html.js
```

start.js has my main server code. That file gets executed via command line using 'node start.js'. Once started, my server begins listening on port 3000. The code in start.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var UserProfileHandler = require('./app/handlers/UserProfileHandler');

app.configure(function () {
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/');

  app.use(express.logger({ stream: expressLogFile }));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

var routes = {
    userProfiles: new UserProfileHandler()
};

function start() {
    routeConfig.setup(app, routes);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("SUCCESS: Server listening on port %d in %s mode", port, app.settings.env);
}

exports.start = start;
exports.app = app;
```

My routes.js file has the following:

```
function setup(app, routes) {
  viewSetup(app);
  apiSetup(app, routes);
}

function viewSetup(app) {
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("/home.html");
  });

  app.get('/home.html', function (req, res) {
    res.render("/home.html");
  });
}

function apiSetup(app, routes) {
  app.get('/api/userProfiles/:username', routes.userProfiles.getUserProfiles);
}
```

I am trying to load home.html in a browser window. I attempt this by visiting `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/home.html`. Unfortunately, none of these work. In fact, I receive an error that says:

Express 500 Error: Failed to lookup view "/home.html"

I know that I'm close. If I visit `http://localhost:3000/api/userProfiles/me` I receive a JSON response back like I'm expecting. For some reason, i can't seem to return HTML though. My home.html file looks like the following.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/resources/javascript/home.html.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    We're up and running! <img src='/resources/images/up.png' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Its a pretty basic HTML file. Even if the HTML comes back though, I'm concerned the JavaScript file and Image it references won't be accessible. I'm concerned of this because I'm not really sure how paths and such work in Node.

How do I get home.html to work in my Node setup?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried app.use(express.static(__dirname));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as your view file is in same folder as your main file, below changes should make it work

#### 1.change the view folder configuration line

from

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');//wont work
```

to

```
app.set('views', __dirname);//will work
```

#### 2.change view render lines

from

```
res.render("/home.html");//wont work
```

to

```
res.render("home.html");//will work
```

with both the changes, the view should be working fine

### update to below comments.

the issue you mentioned regarding the images,css and js is due to the static folder configuration which should be changed from

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));
```

as your static folder is named `resources`.

but make sure in your view you are refering the css/js/image files like

eg:

```
/css/style.css 
/images/up.png
/images/down.png
/javascript/home.html.js
```

from your view file

Also if the above dint work, check if you have given the path correctly and also you can try by taking the

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));
```

before the

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
```

lines like

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  //try changing the position of above line in app.configure and resatrt node app
  app.use(express.logger({ stream: expressLogFile }));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);          
});
```

Comment: Its the little things that will drive you nuts :). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oops, there's one other issue I guess. It still won't access the javascript file and the image file though. How do I configure my server to handle that accordingly?

Comment: Hmmm.... i'm still getting a 404 when I attempt to reference anything in the resources directory.

Comment: @NodeNewbie: did you restart the app after changing the older line to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));` also make sure you are having the links in view page with a slash in beginning.

Comment: @NodeNewbie: this should work according to the folder structure you have shared. are you using a custom 404 handler in your routes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the app after I changed the older line. In addition, I do NOT have a custom 404 handler in my routes.

Comment: may be you could try changing the position of the changed line in you `app.configure` as i put in my update

Comment: Figured it out. It needs     app.use('/resources', express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));  See this: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem in my case is
app.set('./views');
look for the dot, dont know why but the dot will mess it up.
I had it like this
app.set('/views') and no matter what i did couldt find the folder until added the dot.